# AngularJS/node.js/mongoDB. Trying to delete a row from a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Anyone got any idea why this goes wrong?

```
        $scope.removeProduct = function(product){

    console.log(product._id);
    $http.delete("/api/products/" + product._id)
                .success(function (data) {
                    if (data.status == 1) {
                            console.log("got here");

    var index = $scope.vehicles.indexOf(product);
    $scope.vehicles.splice(index, 1);

                    } else {
                            console.log("Something went wrong", product._id);
                            console.debug();
                    }})

    };
```

This always goes to the else statement.

Comment: why not use something else for your condition like the `statusCode` or `message`

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you handle errors in Angular's http API, nor with promises in general. Why are you testing for a value called status?

```
$scope.removeProduct = function(product){

    $http.delete("/api/products/" + product._id)
        .then(function (response) {
            var index = _.indexOf($scope.data, product);
            var index = $scope.vehicles.indexOf(product);
            $scope.vehicles.splice(index, 1);
        }).catch(function (response) {
            console.log("Something went wrong", product._id, response);
            console.debug();
        }})

};
```

Comment: "Why are you testing for a value called status?" I'm very new at this, I was looking at some other code and I thought it was a built in function. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Better check for "data" variable whether it has "status" or not

```
$scope.removeProduct = function(product) {
  console.log(product._id);
  $http.delete("/api/products/" + product._id)
    .success(function(data) {
      if (data && data.status == 1) {
        console.log("got here");
        var index = _.indexOf($scope.data, product);
        var index = $scope.vehicles.indexOf(product);
        $scope.vehicles.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        console.log("Something went wrong", product._id);
        console.debug();
      }
    });

};
```